# How to uninstall arcanist?

Tags: windows, git, github, arcanist

I am using Windows 7 Professional and I would like to uninstall Arcanist. However, I can't find the uninstall file and I did not find the Phabricator page helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Arcanist is a set of PHP files checked out from a git repository. Simply delete them from where you installed them.